# How to make a button that shows me the next 5 arrays when I used slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, pagination

I have a table with 15+ arrays, I slice it to only show 5 of them but I would want to make a button that shows me the next 5 arrays, is this possible?

This is my code

```
          <tbody>
            <TableRow
              v-for="mandate in filteredMandates.slice(0, 5)"
              :mandate="mandate"
              :theme="getColor(mandate.asset_classification)"
              :key="mandate.isin"
            />
          </tbody>
```

I tried making a button that showed me the next 5 sliced items, but I could not figure it out since I'm still very new to Javascript, the result was sadly just an error

Comment: `v-for="mandate in someComputedProperty"` https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is set 2 data attribute (in the vue script data func)

```js
data(){
 pageIndex: 0,
 pageSize: 5
}
```

Then, your code could look something like this:

```html
<tbody>
  <TableRow
    v-for="mandate in filteredMandates.slice(pageIndex, pageSize)"
    :mandate="mandate"
    :theme="getColor(mandate.asset_classification)"
    :key="mandate.isin"
  />
</tbody>
```

And your next page button would do
`this.pageIndex+=this.pageSize`

To improve this, and avoid slicing the array for every page, you can do something like:

```html
<tbody>
  <TableRow
    v-for="i in pageSize"
    :mandate="filteredMandates[startIndex+i-1]"
    :theme="getColor(filteredMandates[startIndex+i-1].asset_classification)"
    :key="filteredMandates[startIndex+i-1].isin"
  />
</tbody>
```

And your next page button would do the same (`this.pageIndex+=this.pageSize`)

meaning that the original array remains, and is not being duplicated, but you are only moving a page by changing the view start index